# Is it true that in a profinite group any set of generators has a subset of generators converging to 1.

Tags: group-theory, profinite-groups

$\underline{\text{Definition:}}$ We say that a subset $X$ of a profinite group $G$ converges to 1 if every open (normal) subgroup $U$ of $G$ contains all but a finite number of the elements in $X$.

It is known that if $G$ is a profinite group, then there exists a set $X$ converging to 1 such that $\overline{\langle X \rangle}=G$ (where $\overline{\langle X \rangle}$ means the closure of $\langle X \rangle$). This is proven in Ribes and Zalesskii's book "Profinite Groups" Proposition 2.4.4 or in Fried and Jarden's book "field arithmetics" Proposition 17.1.1 ([Douady]).

I am trying to show (I do not know if it is true or not) that if $X$  generates a profinite group $G$, in the sense that $G=\overline{\langle X \rangle}$, then there exists $Y\subseteq X$ such that $G=\overline{\langle Y \rangle}$ and $Y$ converges to 1.

By mirroring the proof on Zalesskii's book "Profinite Groups" Proposition 2.4.4 I have the following:

$\underline{\text{Question:}}$Let $G$  be a profinite group and let $Y$ be a set of generators of $G$. Does it existst $\widetilde{Y}\subseteq Y$ such that $\widetilde{Y}$ is a set of generators converging to 1?

I have been able to show that the following set $\mathcal{P}$ has a maximal element. Where $\mathcal{P}$ is defined as follows:

Consider the set $\mathcal{P}$ of all the pairs $(N,X_N)$, where $N\triangleleft_c G$, $X_N\subseteq Y$ and $X_N\subseteq G-N$ such that

$\bullet$ for every open subgroup $U$ of $G$ containing $N$, $X_N-U$ is a finite set;
and

$\bullet$ $G=\overline{\langle X_N,N\rangle}$.

The fact that $\mathcal{P}$ has a maximal element comes from Zorn's Lemma  applied with this partial ordering:
$(N, X_N)\preceq (M,X_M)$ if $N\geq M$, $X_N\subset X_M$ and $X_M-X_N\subseteq N$.

Let  $(M,X)$ be the maximal element in $\mathcal{P}$.

I would like to have that $M=1$. But I am not able to get this. This is what is done in the book: Every profinite group $G$ admits a set of generators converging to 1:

They define $\mathcal{P}$ in a similar way, but without asking that $X_N\subseteq Y$. And so they get a maximal element in $\mathcal{P}$, namely $(M,X)$. They assume that $M\not=1$. Then, let $U\triangleleft_o G$ be such that $U\cup M$ is a proper subgroup of $M$. Then they choose a finite subset $T$ of $M-(U\cap M)$ such that $M=\langle T, U\cap M\rangle$. And then they have that $(U\cap M, X\cup T)\in \mathcal{P}$.  But in our case, I can not ensure that $(U\cap M, X\cup T)\in \mathcal{P} $ since $T$ might not be a subset of  $Y$.

Finally they show that $(M,X) \preceq (U\cap M, X\cup T)$ which is a contradiction. Thus $M=1$.

Is this even true, in my head it makes sense, but I am not sure?
If it is not true in general, is it true for any class of group?

Any idea would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Let $G$ be a profinite group that is not finitely generated, and $H$ be a non-trivial finite group. Then $G\times H$ is profinite, and the set of generators $X=G\times (H\setminus \{e\})$ has no subset that converges to $1$. In fact, as $G\times\{e\}$ is open in $G\times H$ and $X\cap (G\times\{e\})=\emptyset$, any subset of $X$ that converges to $1$ must be finite, but $G$ and hence $G\times H$ is not finitely generated.

The technique can be used to show that the statement holds iff the profinite group is finitely generated.